# Reweight a graph to give it a small max cut

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected, unweighted graph.  I wish to assign weights (possibly negative, not all zero) to the edges to minimize the value of:
$$\frac{m}{\|w\|}$$
where $m$ is the value of the maximum *magnitude* cut on the new weighted graph, and $w$ is the $|E|$-length vector containing the new edge weights.

What is the smallest I can make $\frac{m}{\|w\|}$?  Can I make it $o(1)$ (little-oh)?  Is there a polynomial time procedure for generating some $w$ that comes within a constant factor of the best value for $\frac{m}{\|w\|}$?